# Slideshow in JavaScript with dynamic display of time and content

Tags: javascript, json, slideshow, settimeout, setinterval

I would like to update an `HTML`  container with content from a JSON file. But I would like to be able to do it dynamically and change the display time interval without refreshing the page by manually setting the values of `jsonobj["PD1_ta"], jsonobj["PD2_ta"], jsonobj["PD3_ta"]` (they are my timer values) .

**In a few words :** I would like to do a dynamic HTML slideshow loop with different custom display times for each slide and dynamic updating content.

I tried many solutions such as :

- write the json call synchronously inside the main `setInterval`
  function
- write the json call asynchronously inside the main
  `setInterval` function
- write the json call synchronously in a separate
  `setInterval` function
- write the json call asynchronously in a
  separate `setInterval` function

But none of them work.

```
var jsonobj= {};
jsonobj["PD1_ta"] = {{PD_data["PD1_ta"]}};
jsonobj["PD2_ta"] = {{PD_data["PD2_ta"]}};
jsonobj["PD3_ta"] = {{PD_data["PD3_ta"]}};    
jsonobj["PD1_titre"] = "{{PD_data["PD1_titre"]}}";
jsonobj["PD2_titre"] = "{{PD_data["PD2_titre"]}}";
jsonobj["PD3_titre"] = "{{PD_data["PD3_titre"]}}";

setInterval(
    function() {
        // Set the global configs to synchronous 
        $.ajaxSetup({
            async: false
        });

        $.getJSON('/getallitems.json', function(data) {   
            jsonobj = data;
        });

        // Set the global configs back to asynchronous 
        $.ajaxSetup({
            async: true
        });

        setTimeout(
        function(){
            var output = "";
            output += '<p>';
            output += '<a style="color: yellow;">'+ jsonobj["PD1_titre"]+'</a>';
            output += '</p>';
            document.getElementById("fieldstobeupdated").innerHTML = output;
        },0);

        setTimeout(
        function(){
            var output = "";
            output += '<p>';
            output += '<a style="color: yellow;">'+ jsonobj["PD2_titre"]+'</a>';
            output += '</p>';
            document.getElementById("fieldstobeupdated").innerHTML = output;
        },jsonobj["PD1_ta"]);

        setTimeout(
        function(){
            var output = "";
            output += '<p>';
            output += '<a style="color: yellow;">'+ jsonobj["PD3_titre"]+'</a>';
            output += '</p>';
            document.getElementById("fieldstobeupdated").innerHTML = output;
        },jsonobj["PD1_ta"]+jsonobj["PD2_ta"]);

    },jsonobj["PD1_ta"]+jsonobj["PD2_ta"]+jsonobj["PD3_ta"]);
```

Maybe there is another way? Is it possible?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: `{{PD_data["PD1_ta"]}}` is that some template engine?

Comment: @Petroff Yes, it's a Python/Bottle template

Answer (score 0):

If you need different times don't use `setInterval` use `setTimeout` instead:

```
function loop() {

    // Set the global configs to synchronous 
    $.ajaxSetup({
        async: false
    });

    $.getJSON('/getallitems.json', function(data) {   
        jsonobj = data;
    });

    // Set the global configs back to asynchronous 
    $.ajaxSetup({
        async: true
    });

    setTimeout(
    function(){
        var output = "";
        output += '<p>';
        output += '<a style="color: yellow;">'+ jsonobj["PD1_titre"]+'</a>';
        output += '</p>';
        document.getElementById("fieldstobeupdated").innerHTML = output;
    },0);

    setTimeout(
    function(){
        var output = "";
        output += '<p>';
        output += '<a style="color: yellow;">'+ jsonobj["PD2_titre"]+'</a>';
        output += '</p>';
        document.getElementById("fieldstobeupdated").innerHTML = output;
    },jsonobj["PD1_ta"]);

    setTimeout(
    function(){
        var output = "";
        output += '<p>';
        output += '<a style="color: yellow;">'+ jsonobj["PD3_titre"]+'</a>';
        output += '</p>';
        document.getElementById("fieldstobeupdated").innerHTML = output;
    },jsonobj["PD1_ta"]+jsonobj["PD2_ta"]);

    setTimeout(loop, jsonobj["PD1_ta"]+jsonobj["PD2_ta"]+jsonobj["PD3_ta"]);
}
setTimeout(loop, jsonobj["PD1_ta"]+jsonobj["PD2_ta"]+jsonobj["PD3_ta"]);
```